# Compose a list by repeating the elements of a list in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I know that

```
                  (define (repe k n) (make-list k n))
```

compose a list where *n* appears *k* times but... How can I construct a similar sentence for which *k* is the first element and *n* the second of a previous list?

My

```
             (define (repe x) (make-list car(x) cdr(x)) list)
```

does not seem to work.

On the other hand, I want the second element of the list *n* not to be a number but a letter. How can it be done (since *make-list* seems to be defined just for numbers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are applied like this: `(car x)` and `(cdr x)`, not like `car(x)` and `cdr(x)`.

And `(cdr x)` is a list - the second element is `(car (cdr x))`, or `(cadr x)` for short.

Your description isn't entirely clear, but it seems like you're looking for

```
(define (repe xs) (make-list (car xs) (cadr xs)))
```

Examples:

```
> (repe (list 4 #\Z))
'(#\Z #\Z #\Z #\Z)
> (repe (list 3 "hello"))
'("hello" "hello" "hello")
> (repe '(2 (+ 1 1)))
'((+ 1 1) (+ 1 1))
```

Comment: That is fine. Thank you.

Comment: btw use `first` and `second` for `car` and `cadr`, respectively; `rest` for `cdr`

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim Why? `first`, `second`, and `rest` does not exist in the current Scheme reports (R5RS, R6RS, R7RS) so the only place it works is if you use `#lang racket`. I often write in `#lang racket/base` and it is not available there either without explicit adding it with `(require racket/list)`. Note that we do not know if OP uses `#lang racket` since `scheme` is also tagged.

Comment: @Sylwester Ah I thought it was also immanent in Scheme ... well, McCarthy and Steve Russel wanted to rename `car` and `cdr` as `first` and `rest` but it was too late, `car` and `cdr` sticked to the people. As you can read here http://www.iwriteiam.nl/HaCAR_CDR.html in one of the emails of Steve Russel.